# Azure app service authentication with Azure AD - Why is an AD app required?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have been following this link to set up the in-built configuration using Azure AD into my App service instance.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad

Additionally I dont want users to generate token with audience as client-id of AD app, so I have added App ID Url to my AD app = http://example.com, and added the same URL to allowed audiences in Advanced auth settings in App service instance.

So now users with token having this URL as audience are able to hit my service,

Now that my users are not generating token with audience as the client ID of AD app, I'm not sure why this client ID has to be configured(mandatory) in App service auth settings. Please help me understand.

Comment: I guess it's because the App Service auth module enables interactive AAD authentication as well, and you need a client id for that. Your API doesn't really need interactive auth of course. Just one of the reasons I prefer to configure auth inside the app, not in App Service.

Comment: My intention in using the in-built auth was to avoid writing a middleware that validates the token, syncs token validation keys with AD etc. Are you saying that the client-id configuration is only for interactive login?

Comment: That's my thinking at least. And the tokens are pretty standard so a lot of standard JWT validation libraries work. Don't do your own validation, the ASP.NET Core JWT handler also downloads the signing keys automatically.